# searching for matches between two sheets and copying specific values from specific column

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 sheets , in sheet1 i have a column with article names(im geeting my names from sheet1) , in sheet 2 i have a column like that two "Nom de l'entité" (doing a search by header in sheet 2), if i find a match in sheet 2 , i look for a column called "longueur" and copy the value and put it in the offset(0,1) of the article name in sheet 1 . Im a beginner but this is what i did so far.I need to loop through all the article names hoping to fin them all in sheet 2 . Here's a link of photo to see what im trying to do exactly : https://postimg.cc/pmLY9dXc

```
Sub longueur()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lecture") '<== Sheet that has raw data
Dim wss As Worksheet: Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1") 'sheet that we re gonna paste longueur into
Dim FoundName As Range, FoundLongueur As Range
Dim c As Range

Set FoundName = ws.Range("A1:DS1").Find("NOM DE L'ENTITÉ") '<== Header name to search for
Set FoundLongueur = ws.Range("A1:DS1").Find("LONGUEUR")    '<== Header name to search for in case we already found name match
If Not FoundName Is Nothing And Not FoundLongueur Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In Range(wss.Cells.Range("D:D")) 'go back to sheet1 to get the names to search for
    If c.value = FoundName Then
    FoundLongueur.Offset(0, 1).value
    End If
Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub longueur()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rngName As Range, rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim colLongueur As Integer, iLastRow As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Feuil1") 'sheet that we re gonna paste longueur into
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Lecture") '<== Sheet that has raw data
 
    ' find column NOM DE L'ENTITÉ on sheet 2
    Set rng = ws2.Range("A1:DS1").Find("NOM DE L'ENTITÉ")
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find 'NOM DE L'ENTITÉ' on " & ws2.Name, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' expand to end of column
    Set rngName = ws2.Range(rng, ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    ' find column LONGUEUR on sheet 2
    Set rng = ws2.Range("A1:DS1").Find("LONGUEUR")
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find 'LONGUEUR' on " & ws2.Name, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    colLongueur = rng.Column

    ' scan sheet 1 col D
    iLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In ws1.Range("D1:D" & iLastRow)
        ' find name on sheet 2
        Set rng = rngName.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "No Match"
        Else
            ' copy value from column LONGUEUR
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(rng.Row, colLongueur)
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Ended"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you're litteraly saving my internship everytime ty !

Comment: @Chayma I hope you are learning something and not just [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: technically here i am learning way more than what i learned during 3 years in college , and before i ask my questions i really put effort in searching for a solution. Plus if i only copy paste i am the one whos gonna be clueless within a few years ‍♀️